# Can't enqueue scripts in the footer?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

The WordPress codex [says](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/):

([old codex page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160120120740/https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script))

> $in_footer
>
> (boolean) (optional) Normally scripts are placed in the 
>   section. If this parameter is true the script is placed at the bottom
>   of the . This requires the theme to have the wp_footer() hook in
>   the appropriate place. Note that you have to enqueue your script
>   before wp_head is run, even if it will be placed in the footer. (New
>   in WordPress 2.8) Default: false

So I added `true` after each script's `src path`:

```
/**
     * JavaScript
     */

    function my_scripts_method() {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');

    function media_queries_script() {
        wp_register_script( 'mediaqueries', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/css3-mediaqueries.js', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'mediaqueries' );
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'media_queries_script');

    function custom_script() {
        wp_register_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_script');

    function replace_script() {
        wp_register_script( 'replace', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.ba-replacetext.min.js', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'replace' );
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'replace_script');
```

But the scripts are still being included in the header.

Any suggestions to fix that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Where did you put your code ?

1. the "true" arguments goes in the `wp_register_script();`, not the `wp_enqueue_script() ;`

the functions is:

`<?php wp_enqueue_script('handle', 'src', 'deps', 'ver', 'in_footer'); ?>`

meaning

```
    <?php wp_enqueue_script('NameMySccript', 'path/to/MyScript', 
'dependencies_MyScript', 'VersionMyScript', 'InfooterTrueorFalse'); ?>
```

E.G.

`<?php
wp_enqueue_script('my_script', WP_CONTENT_URL . 'plugins/my_plugin/my_script.js', array('jquery', 'another_script'), '1.0.0', true);
?>`

2. does your theme have `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`  at the end of the page ?

3.add the action with `add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'your function');`

That being said , your best practice would be :

```
<?php  
if (function_exists('load_my_scripts')) {  
    function load_my_scripts() {  
        if (!is_admin()) {  
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );  
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js');  
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  
        wp_register_script('myscript', bloginfo('template_url').'/js/myScript.js'__FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );  
        wp_enqueue_script('myscript');  
        }  
    }  
}  
add_action('init', 'load_my_scripts');  
?>
```

or `add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'dl_register_js');`

Comment: Thanks it is working now but I realized that placing the `true` in either `wp_enqueue` or `wp-register_script` work just fine.

Comment: @krembo99 The [`wp_register_script()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_register_script/) takes the same amount of arguments and both add to the `$wp_scripts` global array and the `data` subarray. Combined the wrong information with the awfull readability of your answer, I've to give you a -1 (will be removed on rework).

Comment: For me the missing piece of the puzzle was `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` did not exist in the page template.  After that, the `true` parameter in `wp_enqueue_script` did its job.

Answer (score 9):

You are passing a bool value to the dependency param. Try this:

```
 wp_enqueue_script(
      'replace', 
       get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.ba-replacetext.min.js',
       array('jquery'), 
       '', 
       true
);
```

Comment: This is technically the right answer for his question based on the code in the question.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and after doing some search I was missing this function in my custom theme:

```
 <?php wp_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to simplify the answer here..  When using wp_enqueue_script or wp_register_script to load a script in the footer, you need to make sure you include the other params too, even if they are blank.

I was trying..

```
wp_register_script( 'rrssb', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/includes/rrssb.min.js',  true);
```

Which didn't work as @janoChen has noticed. Wordpress calls for

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

So you need to include `'',` for the parameters you are not using if you want to declare the function inline. Therefore the code below works as planned.

```
wp_register_script( 'rrssb', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/includes/rrssb.min.js', '', '', true);
```

Subsequently you can declare the function in an array like format like @Brian Fegter shows.

Comment: You need to provide the empty strings only where placeholders are needed.

Comment: Ah yes! Of Course, only `'',` where parameters are required, not optional.

Answer (score 2):

If you enqueue a script to the header but declare a dependency to a script enqueued to the footer, WordPress will move the footer script to the header to make it available to the dependent script/s.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official WordPress documentation (Last Checked - May 2018):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

and personal experience of 7+ years.

1. You should try always use '**wp_enqueue_scripts**' function for better compatibility with installed plugins/themes.

   ```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','your_plugin_enqueue');
   ```
2. You can find more about using official docs [Usage here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#usage)

   ```
      /**** wp_register_script, wp_enqueue_script, wp_dequeue_script ***

            *** Personal recommendation
            *  - I strongly recommend registering all scripts before enqueueing,
            *  again -> for better compatibility with other developers. 
            *  :::: For example, so others could manipulate the position 
            *       of your scripts using the wp_dequeue_*type* method. 
            *       (wp_dequeue_script, wp_dequeue_style,...)

            *** Official Docs
            *   $in_footer
            *      - (bool) (Optional) Whether to enqueue the script before </body> instead of in the <head>. Default 'false'.
            *      - Default value: false
            *
            ***/

            // examples:

     function your_plugin_enqueue(){



            wp_dequeue_script('some_script(s)'); // remove conflicting script

            wp_register_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer=true ); 
            wp_enqueue_script($handle);
            wp_register_script('some_script(s)', $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer=true);  // re-enqueue scripts after yours for example to elimination of conflicts

            wp_enqueue_script('some_script(s)');

     }


     add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','your_plugin_enqueue');
   ```

**P.S. If you find this answer useful, please give it an '▲' (*ArrowUP*), if you think that it can be improved, please comment below.**