# How to register or enqueue script and stop it being called in head?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

i have below code which enqueues javascript.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.flexslider', get_template_directory_uri().'/library/js/flex-slider/jquery.flexslider-min.js',  array( 'jquery' ));
```

Above code is not in functions.php. it is in library/siteframework.php

What i understand is in order to any javascript work in wp, it got to be registered or enqueued.

I want to enqueue the javascript and don't want to call it in head.

With above code in place, html source automatically calls script in head as below...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/WHMFront/library/js/flex-slider/jquery.flexslider-min.js'>
```

if i remove enqueueing code then script call disappears from head.

I tried below code in functions.php. did not work.

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
wp_register_script( 'jquery.flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/js/flex-slider/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

wp_enqueue_script('jquery.flexslider');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );

How to register or enqueue script and stop it being called in head?

Comment: Is there `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in your theme?

Comment: yes @RohitKishore

Comment: @RohitKishore what is the difference between the code??

Comment: The arguments in the last

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37960/cant-enqueue-scripts-in-the-footer

Comment: That worked. i checked without clearing cache. Can you please tell me what that last argument means? @RohitKishore

Comment: The last one is `in_footer` argument. Please mark answer correct if that helped you.

Comment: I have marked as correct. However, there can be a dispute. Because i wanted to not to call anywhere (and call it where i exactly wanted). And the solution is calling the script in footer. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `siteframework.php` file change code to:

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.flexslider', get_template_directory_uri().'/library/js/flex-slider/jquery.flexslider-min.js',  array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true);
```